# Error while fetching extension. XHR failed

Tags: visual-studio-code, installation, python-extensions

This is my first time installing and using VSCode, and when I try to install a python extension inside a VSCode application I get the error "Error While fetching extension. XHR failed" . How do I fix it?
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdWdO.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem usually occurs because of the proxy settings.
try the following steps:

1.setting

2.proxy settings

3.Enable Detect automatically setting

4.restart

or

go to google search https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/
search for python then install python.

Answer (score 2):

first you open Vscode programming and do the following steps.

1. Press f1
2. Search user setting
3. Click enter
4. Search on user setting "proxy"
5. Click enter
6. Look for "use the proxy support for extensions."
7. Change override to `on`

Answer (score -1):

vscode->option-> user-> search 'proxy' ->clear 'http proxy" , it will be ok

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).