# How to fix "Error while fetching extensions, XHR failed" on VS Code Winodws

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

When I search extensions on VS Code, online, this error pops-up all the time and unable to find any extensions.

When the issue appeared I tried the followings.

1. Set "http.proxySupport": "on" in user settings, under the proxy. Restart the VS Code.
2. Complete re-installation of VS Code. Including PC reboot after the re-installation.
3. Installing using an offline VSIX works anyway.

How can I resolve this issue? Because I cannot install any extension online thru search.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error while fetching extension. XHR failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72781369/error-while-fetching-extension-xhr-failed) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70177216/visual-studio-code-error-while-fetching-extensions-xhr-failed?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C207.6068)

Comment: Yes. I tried all of them, but still the issue is observing. I'm trying to use bit older version of VS Code to check, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

For Linux (Ubuntu) I found this worked:

Launch VSCode as su:

```
sudo code
```

It will prompt you to add some additional command line arguments.

Add those (you may need to create a directory where VSCode can store some stuff - I used `~/VSCodeDataDir`)

```
sudo code --no-sandbox --user-data-dir ~/VSCodeDataDir
```

and now VS code will launch and allow you to get to extensions (with a warning that it is not safe to launch as root).

Install the extensions you need.
Then close VSCode and relaunch without "sudo" and things should work.

Launching VSCode with administrator privileges on Windows may also work on that platform.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still looks for answer, this could be caused by VS Code running in "restricted mode". I think it happens when you loaded a downloaded script. At bottom left corner, it tells you if you are in that mode, click on it, switch it to "Trusted mode".

The solution also applies to formatting (Alt-Shift-F) not working.